# Delphi android create action bar

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

**SITUATION**

I am creating an app for a customer and my boss told me to add an action bar with a button that displays some other things. This screenshot will clarify:

[image]

The dark green bar above with (and the white text) is a TLayout aligned at **Top** with a ColorBox. On the right you can see that I have a button and, when you click on it, you see a TListBox with some options. When the user clicks on them, an action is performed.

---

**PROBLEM**

The TListBox is not visible when the form creates. When you click on the button the box appears thanks to this code:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonMenuClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

 //oflowmen is the TListBox
 oflowmen.Visible := not oflowmen.Visible;
 if oflowmen.Visible then
 begin
  oflowmen.ApplyStyleLookup;
  oflowmen.RealignContent;
 end;

end;
```

This code works fine because when you click on the button, the TListBox appears/disappears, but this is not enough. I want my box to disappear in 2 ways:

1. When I click again on the button (solution that I have implemented above)
2. When I click somewhere in the screen (excluding the button of course)

How can I implement the second case?

**Note:** I put a screenshot of a 32 bit exe instead of a screenshot from my android test device, but it's the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep, behavior of FMX components are different on different platform, this is not a secret.

Alternative solution: use TComboBox -- it's already has behavior you need (`click somewhere in the screen`). See screen sample:

[image]

Answer on your question: change HitTest property to False for TListBox and for all other controls on your form and do control of MouseDown. Not good idea (Halloween solution).

Code sample:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.TabControl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    ToolBar2: TToolBar;
    Button1: TButton;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Button2: TButton;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  private
    FLIstBoxVisible: Boolean;
    procedure SetListBoxVisible(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    property ListBoxVisible: Boolean read FLIstBoxVisible write SetListBoxVisible;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.DropDown;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBoxVisible := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if ListBoxVisible then
    ListBoxVisible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetListBoxVisible(const Value: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to Form1.ComponentCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Form1.Components[I] = ListBox1 then
        Continue;

      (Form1.Components[I] as TControl).HitTest := not Value;

      if Value then
        (Form1.Components[I] as TControl).OnMouseDown := FormMouseDown
      else
        (Form1.Components[I] as TControl).OnMouseDown := nil;
    end;

  if Value then
    ListBox1.RealignContent;
  FLIstBoxVisible := Value;
  ListBox1.Visible := Value;
end;

end.
```

And form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnMouseDown = FormMouseDown
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object ToolBar2: TToolBar
      Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      object Button1: TButton
        Align = Left
        Size.Width = 80.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 1
        Text = 'ComboBox'
        OnClick = Button1Click
      end
      object Button2: TButton
        Align = Right
        Position.X = 560.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 80.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
        Text = 'ListBox'
        OnClick = Button2Click
      end
    end
    object ComboBox1: TComboBox
      Align = Left
      Items.Strings = (
        'item 1'
        'item 2'
        'item 3'
        'item 4'
        'item 5')
      Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    HitTest = False
    Position.X = 224.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 128.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    Items.Strings = (
      'Item 1'
      'Item 2'
      'Item 3'
      'Item 4')
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    Viewport.Width = 196.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 196.000000000000000000
  end
  object TabControl1: TTabControl
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 440.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabIndex = 0
    TabOrder = 2
    TabPosition = PlatformDefault
    object TabItem1: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = True
      Size.Width = 70.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'TabItem1'
      OnMouseDown = FormMouseDown
    end
    object TabItem2: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 70.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 26.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'TabItem2'
      OnMouseDown = FormMouseDown
    end
  end
end
```

Tested on DX10 (without Update 1) and Android 5.1.1