# Delphi Android overflow menu in action bar not working

Tags: android, delphi

In my (very simple) Android app written in Delphi 11.3 I want to have an 'overflow' menu as described [here](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/creating-an-overflow-menu-on-android/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294907/delphi-android-create-action-bar).

I followed the instructions from [here](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/creating-an-overflow-menu-on-android/) (which seem quite straightforward), but the menu does not appear! Also, I could not understand how to associate an event to each listbox (which emulates the menu) item. Quite different a way from old and good Delphi VCL indeed!

Could someone out there help me with this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Here are my project code and form:

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;

end.

unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.WebBrowser,
  FMX.Effects, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ShadowEffect1: TShadowEffect;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
      { Private declarations }
  public
      { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
    // Do whatever you want to do here
    if WebBrowser1.CanGoBack then
      WebBrowser1.GoBack;
    Key := 0; // Set Key = 0 if you want to prevent the default action
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.torry.net/')
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Visible := not ListBox1.Visible;
  if ListBox1.Visible then
  begin
    ListBox1.ApplyStyleLookup;
    ListBox1.RealignContent;
  end;
end;

end.

object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnKeyUp = FormKeyUp
  OnShow = FormShow
  DesignerMasterStyle = 3
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 48.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    TintColor = claBlack
    object ListBox1: TListBox
      Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
      Position.X = 440.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 200.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 176.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 1
      Visible = False
      DisableFocusEffect = True
      Items.Strings = (
        'About'
        'Exit')
      DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
      DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
      DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
      Viewport.Width = 200.000000000000000000
      Viewport.Height = 176.000000000000000000
      object ShadowEffect1: TShadowEffect
        Distance = 3.000000000000000000
        Direction = 45.000000000000000000
        Softness = 0.300000011920929000
        Opacity = 0.600000023841857900
        ShadowColor = claBlack
      end
    end
    object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
      Align = Right
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 587.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 48.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 48.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'detailstoolbutton'
      Text = 'SpeedButton1'
      OnClick = SpeedButton1Click
    end
  end
  object WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 432.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    WindowsEngine = IEOnly
  end
end
```

Comment: Based on the code from your DFM its seems that you have placed your `ListBox1` as child component of your `ToolBar1` and then you set the `Y` position of your `ListBox1` to 56 which is greater than the height of the `ToolBar1`. So by default such component would not be rendered as it is outside of the Clip Rectangle of its parent component. So try changing parent of your `ListBox1` by dragging it from `ToolBar1` to `Form1` in Object Tree window. This should result in both `ToolBar1` and `ListBox1` to have same depth in Object Tree window indicating that they have same parent.

Comment: Hi, @SilverWarrior! Thanks for your suggestion. I moved the ListBox1 to the same level of ToolBar1 and the menu now appears - but just the first option ("About")! I have set the ListBox1 height to 176 following the instructions from https://blogs.embarcadero.com/creating-an-overflow-menu-on-android/, but it seems this doest not work. Any further hints?

Comment: I believe that is because your `ListBox1` is being obstructed by your `WebBrowser1` component. The problem with `TWebBrowser` component is that this is not a standard FMX component but a wrapper for system default browser. And it appears that its contents are always rendered on top of any other component regardless of their positional order.  So you should probably ask a new question on whether it is possible to render any other FMX component on top of `TWebBrowser`.

Comment: Hi, @SilverWarrior! I am truly appalled!!! I got to develop this very same app with a beautiful overflowing menu (and a zoomed out webbrowser to fit the width of the screen without much trouble in Free Pascal and the Lazarus IDE using the Lazarus Android Module Wizard (https://github.com/jmpessoa/lazandroidmodulewizard). I was attempting to create a version in Delphi in the hope that it would be in any wy better, but I am much disappointed!

Comment: `LAMW` is entirely using native Android visual components while `Delphi FMX` is not. Well actually `Delphi FMX` does offer use of several native visual components. But compared to `LAMW` it si quite limited in this area.

Comment: In other words, despite several limitations (especially the lack of documentation) LAMW offers a much better experience for the development of Android apps using Pascal than Delphi with either FireMonkey or FMX. I am sticking to it.